# Pass parameters to pig jython script

Tags: jython, apache-pig

I'm looking to embed a pig script in python, but I need to pass a few parameters to the python script and they don't seem to populate down.

If I call my pig script directly I can use: `$PIGDIR/bin/pig -f $SCRIPT_DIR/../pig/score_cert_messages.pig -param libDir=DYNAMIC_STRING` and libDir is bound correctly.

When loading my python script the same way, however, I don't get anything in `sys.argv`. Are `-param` values accessible (within the python code) when loading the python through pig, or do I have to manually call the script with jython and generate the `scriptContext` (if so, anybody have a sample)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue. Check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2165.

Answer (score 0):

Almost two years later and I still could not do it without a workaround.  Basically, I've created an environmental variable that I use in my script:

```
$ export file_in=filename; pig -useHCatalog ./POC_Python_Wrapper.py
```

and in the script:

```
import os
file_in = os.getenv('file_in', 'Unknown')
```